# pandas count unique values considering column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df as the following:

```
col1  col2
-----------
a      1b
a      1b
a      1a
b      2a
b      3f
```

And I want to count how many unique pairs each col1 element has:
output:

```
(a, 2)
(b, 2)
```

Comment: groupby & nunique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to count the number if unique values on `col2` after grouping on `col1` -

```
df.groupby(['col1']).nunique()['col2']
#col1
#a    2
#b    2
```

If you want it in the format you mentioned, you can pass it into `zip` -

```
list(zip(df.groupby(['col1']).nunique()['col2'].index, df.groupby(['col1']).nunique()['col2'].values))                           
[('a', 2), ('b', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

As a DataFrame

```
df.groupby("col1", as_index=False).nunique()

    col1 col2
0    a    2
1    b    2
```

In the format mentioned;

```
list(df.groupby("col1", as_index=False).nunique().to_records(index=False))

[('a', 2), ('b', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.drop_duplicates(['col1', 'col2'])[['col1']].value_counts()
```

or

```
list(map(tuple, df.groupby('col1', as_index=False).nunique().values))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size()
```

Comment: That doesn't give the expected result

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).